# How to remove duplicate values from oracle join?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, inner-join

I want to create a view that present only the results and not present the duplicates,  I have 3 tables in oracle database:

The first table contain general information about a person

```
+-----------+-------+-------------+
| ID        | Name  | Birtday_date|
+-----------+-------+-------------+
| 1         | Byron | 12/10/1998  |
| 2         | Peter | 01/11/1973  |
| 4         | Jose  | 05/02/2008  |
+-----------+-------+-------------+
```

The second table contain information about a telephone of the people in the first table.

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| ID    |ID_Person |CELL_TYPE | NUMBER   |
+-------+- --------+----------+----------+
| 1221  | 1        | 3        | 099141021|
| 2221  | 1        | 2        | 099091925|
| 3222  | 1        | 1        | 098041013|
| 4321  | 2        | 1        | 088043153|
| 4561  | 2        | 2        | 090044313|
| 5678  | 4        | 1        | 092049013|
| 8990  | 4        | 2        | 098090233|
+----- -+----------+----------+----------+
```

The Third table contain information about a email of the people in the first table.

```
+------+----------+----------+---------------+
| ID   |ID_Person |MAIL_TYPE | Email         |
+------+- --------+----------+---------------+
| 221  | 1        | 1        |jdoe@aol.com   |
| 222  | 1        | 2        |jdoe1@aol.com  |
| 421  | 2        | 1        |xx12@yahoo.com |
| 451  | 2        | 2        |dsdsa@gmail.com|
| 578  | 4        | 1        |sasaw1@sdas.com|
| 899  | 4        | 2        |cvcvsd@wew.es  |
+------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

if i do a inner join with this tables the result will do something like that

```
+-----+-------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------+
| ID  | Name  | Birtday_date| CELL_TYPE|  NUMBER  |MAIL_TYPE|Email            |
+-----+-------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------+
| 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 3        | 099141021|1         |jdoe@aol.com    |   
| 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 3        | 099141021|2         |jdoe1@aol.com   |  
| 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 2        | 099091925|1         |jdoe@aol.com    | 
| 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 2        | 099091925|2         |jdoe1@aol.com   | 
| 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 1        | 098041013|1         |jdoe@aol.com    | 
| 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 1        | 098041013|2         |jdoe1@aol.com   |
| 2   | Peter | 01/11/1973  | 1        | 088043153|1         |xx12@yahoo.com  |
| 2   | Peter | 01/11/1973  | 1        | 088043153|2         |dsdsa@gmail.com |
| 2   | Peter | 01/11/1973  | 2        | 090044313|1         |xx12@yahoo.com  |
| 2   | Peter | 01/11/1973  | 2        | 090044313|2         |dsdsa@gmail.com |
| 4   | Jose  | 05/02/2008  | 1        | 088043153|1         |sasaw1@sdas.com |
| 4   | Jose  | 05/02/2008  | 1        | 088043153|2         |cvcvsd@wew.es   |
| 4   | Jose  | 05/02/2008  | 2        | 088043153|1         |sasaw1@sdas.com |
| 4   | Jose  | 05/02/2008  | 2        | 088043153|2         |cvcvsd@wew.es   |
+-----+-------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------+
```

So the result that i will to present in a view is the next

```
+-----+-------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------+
| ID  | Name  | Birtday_date| CELL_TYPE|  NUMBER  |MAIL_TYPE|Email            |
+-----+-------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------+
| 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 3        | 099141021|1         |jdoe@aol.com    |   
| 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  |          |          |2         |jdoe1@aol.com   |  
| 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 2        | 099091925|          |                | 
| 1   | Byron | 12/10/1998  | 1        | 098041013|          |                | 
| 2   | Peter | 01/11/1973  | 1        | 088043153|1         |xx12@yahoo.com  |
| 2   | Peter | 01/11/1973  |          |          |2         |dsdsa@gmail.com |
| 2   | Peter | 01/11/1973  | 2        | 090044313|          |                |
| 4   | Jose  | 05/02/2008  | 1        | 092049013|1         |sasaw1@sdas.com |
| 4   | Jose  | 05/02/2008  |          |          |2         |cvcvsd@wew.es   |
| 4   | Jose  | 05/02/2008  | 2        | 098090233|          |                |
+-----+-------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------------+
```

I tried to achieve a similar output using

```
case
  when row_number() over (partition by table1.id order by table2.type) = 1
  then table1.value
 end
   as "VALUE"
```

But the result is nothing that I expect and some rows they repeats

Comment: Use left outer join against two table expressions, each one using row_number().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
Create table person(ID int ,Name varchar(20), Birtday_date date)
Insert into person values
(1,'Byron' ,'12/10/1998'),
(2,'Peter' ,'01/11/1973'),
(4,'Jose ' ,'05/02/2008')


Create table phones (ID int,ID_Person int,CELL_TYPE int,NUMBER float)
Insert into phones values
(1221, 1 , 3,099141021),
(2221, 1 , 2,099091925),
(3222, 1 , 1,098041013),
(4321, 2 , 1,088043153),
(4561, 2 , 2,090044313),
(5678, 4 , 1,092049013),
(8990, 4 , 2,098090233)


Create table emails(ID int,ID_Person int, MAIL_TYPE int, Email varchar(100))
Insert into emails values
(221, 1 , 1, 'jdoe@aol.com   '),
(222, 1 , 2, 'jdoe1@aol.com  '),
(421, 2 , 1, 'xx12@yahoo.com '),
(451, 2 , 2, 'dsdsa@gmail.com'),
(578, 4 , 1, 'sasaw1@sdas.com'),
(899, 4 , 2, 'cvcvsd@wew.es  ')

select p.id, p.name, p.Birtday_date,
       case when Lag(number) over(partition by p.id order by p.id,pe.id) = number then null else cell_type end as cell_type,
       case when Lag(number) over(partition by p.id order by p.id,pe.id) = number then null else number end as number,
       mail_type as mail_type, email as email
from person p left join
     (select pp.ID_Person, cell_type, number, mail_type, email,pp.id from
     (select ID_Person, cell_type, number,id,
              row_number() over (partition by ID_Person order by id ) as seqnum
       from phones 
      ) pp left join
      (select ID_Person,
              mail_type, email, 1 as seqnum
       from emails 
      )e on pp.ID_Person = e.ID_Person and pp.seqnum = e.seqnum
     ) pe
on pe.ID_Person = p.Id
order by  p.id, pe.id
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is enumerate the rows and then join on those enumerations.  This is tricky, because you don't know how many are in each list.  Well, there is another method using conditional aggregation:

```
select p.id, p.name, p.birthday,
       max(cell_type) as cell_type, max(number) as number,
       max(mail_type) as mail_type, max(email) as email
from person p left join
     ((select id_person, cell_type, number,
              null as mail_type, null as email,
              row_number() over (partition by id_person order by number) as seqnum
       from phones
      ) union all
      (select id_person, null as cell_type, null as number,
              mail_type, email,
              row_number() over (partition by id_person order by email) as seqnum
       from emails
      )
     ) pe
     on pe.id_person = p.id_person
group by p.id, p.name, p.birthday, pe.seqnum
```